# Material dialog library - prevent dismissing/closing the dialog on onPositive function call

Tags: android, android-dialog, material-design

I am using [this](http://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) Material Dialog library and when I click the positive button, the `onPositive` function is called and the dialog is closed. How can I prevent the dialog from closing/dismissing?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on positive button?

Comment: @DjordjeTankosic nothing, i just want to keep my dialog stay opened

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `autoDismiss(false)` and dismiss the dialog manually in callback method.

```
  new MaterialDialog.Builder(mainActivity)
            .title(R.string.title)
            .autoDismiss(false)
            .content(R.string.content)
            .positiveText(R.string.positive)
            .negativeText(R.string.negative)
            .positiveColor(setColor())
            .onPositive((dialog, which) => {
                // do something positive here
                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .onNegative((dialog, which) => {
                // do something negative here
                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .negativeColor(setColor())
            .typeface(titleAndActions, contentAndListItems)
            .build()
            .show();
```

Comment: @DjordjeTankosic Thanks for the help it worked. I was trying to Override the click before.

Comment: As of the latest version prior to v2 RC, `.callback()` is deprecated. You should use:  `onPositive()` which takes the dialog and a which (option) as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

.autoDismiss no longer exists.
You should use .setCancelable(false) instead.

```
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public MaterialAlertDialogBuilder setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
    return (MaterialAlertDialogBuilder) super.setCancelable(cancelable);
  }
```

Comment: That's only for Back click

Answer (score 0):

autoDismiss() is deprecated. Use setCancelable():

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                .setMessage(R.string.message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ok") { _, _ -> finish() }.show()
```

It prevents the dialog to dismiss when:

- back is pressed
- click outside the dialog